# How do you make a responsive footer like this?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, footer

I want to make the footer look like this in Desktop:
[image: Desktop version]

In mobile it should look like this:

[image: mobile view]

I tried the following, but the text seems to go out of bounds (note this is just one of my prototypes, you would get overwhelmed if I posted all of them here):

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="footercol1" style="line-height:10px;display: flex;">
    <div id="image" style="float: left; margin-left: 25px;">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" width="73" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="word-wrap:normal;max-width:300px;width:50%;float: right; margin-left: 10px;">
      <p style="font-size: 14px;">Text1 blablablablablablablabla</br>
        </br>
        blablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla</br>
        </br>
        blablablablablablalblalbblalblbalblbalblalblbabla<br /> <br /> blablablablabalbalblablalblalbbllabllbalblabla.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="max-width:300px;float: right; width:50%;margin-left: 50px;font-size: 14px;">
      <strong style="color: #489523;">Text 2: </strong> blablablabalbalbalblbalblalblbalblablblalbalblblalblblalblabla <br /><br />
      <p>blablablablablablabalbalbalbalblablbablalblablablablabla</p>
      <br />
      <img class="alignleft" src="https://picsum.photos/70/30" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

FYI: footercol1 doesn't yet contain any CSS rules, hence it's not appended to the question.

**UPDATE**

Text out of bounds problem is also visible in your snippet as well:

**UPDATE 2**

Adding the following CSS rules to `p`:

```
word-break: normal;
white-space: normal;
```

partly solves the overflow problem, but it makes the text quite "crambed" as a side effect. Any clue how to fix that?

[image: out of bounds text]

Comment: Have you read the documentation about bootstrap grid? something like col-xs-12 can help....

Comment: @Sfili_81 I did, hence the classes are included here. `col-xs-12` for the whole "top layer" div you mean? My problem is primarily that the text goes out of bounds, even if I restrict it with `max-width` and similar.

Comment: Another question, why do you use float? and max-width?

Comment: With bootstrap you have some helpers class for flexbox, to set a flex direction column you can use for example .flex-sm-column to your container.

Comment: I am not an expert with flexbox, hence I tried to use what I know...

Comment: Try to add your text inside a p tag for example, and use word-break:break-all (this is only an idea please try and then if you get another error update the question)

Comment: @Sfili_81 tried it already, seems to have no effect. I thought it's maybe a CSS override, but I checked that for every element too in my main CSS file...

Answer (score 3):

You're already using flex on your footercol1, so the easiest would probably be to just to use a media query to define the flex direction.

Something like:

```css
.footercol1 {
  display: flex;
}

p {
 overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .footercol1 {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="footercol1" style="line-height:10px;display: flex;">
    <div id="image" style="float: left; margin-left: 25px;">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" width="73" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="word-wrap:normal;max-width:300px;width:50%;float: right; margin-left: 10px;">
      <p style="font-size: 14px;">Text1 blablablablablablablabla
        <br>
        <br> blablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
        <br>
        <br> blablablablablablalblalbblalblbalblbalblalblbabla
        <br>
        <br> blablablablabalbalblablalblalbbllabllbalblabla.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="max-width:300px;float: right; width:50%;margin-left: 50px;font-size: 14px;">
      <strong style="color: #489523;">Text 2: </strong> <p>blablablabalbalbalblbalblalblbalblablblalbalblblalblblalblabla</p>
      <br>
      <br>
      <p>blablablablablablabalbalbalbalblablbablalblablablablabla</p>
      <br>
      <img class="alignleft" src="https://picsum.photos/70/30" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`flex-direction: row;` is default. You should probably read up on flexbox:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Comment: he tag the question with css... so better use vanilla css not sass

Comment: Fair enough. I've updated the answer reflecting that.

Comment: It's not compulsory to add in code snippets to the answer, but it does tend to improve them (and show the answer working), so I edited the snippet in for you. If you feel particularly aggrieved you're absolutely welcome to roll-back the edit. :)

Comment: This appears to work(?), but my text overflow problem is still there making the result not optically pleasing. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: By not optically pleasing I mean basically not readable...

Comment: @Koronag The problem is also in your snippet too as well, I've updated the question.

Comment: There are multiple ways to solve this @Munchkin. I've updated the answer to reflect one way, using [overflow-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) on all paragraphs with  overflow-wrap: break-word;

Comment: As my update 2 states this is basically the same result - the text wraps, yes, but it gets crammed up..